# Why would Blackguard betray his team openly?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad

In the movie, *The Suicide Squad*, the first team that consists of Savant, Blackguard, Captain Boomerang, TDK, Javelin, and Mongal is ambushed at their landing beach.

Blackguard comes out of hiding and starts shouting and claims he is the one who has given away their landing position to the Corto Maltese military.

We have been shown that all team members have had a capsule bomb implanted in their heads and can be killed instantly by remote detonation. Logically, Blackguard, by revealing publicly that he is a traitor, is subject to instant execution; yet he does it in the open.

Why does he do that? I am not sure if the director tries to establish that Blackguard is an idiot or he has disabled his own bomb somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it was a part of this team being group false protagonist. Maybe the guy thought the enemy would save him and disable it instead of headshooting? Dunno...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having just seen the movie myself the movie does not show his motivations for betraying the "distraction team". He isn't even a major character in the movie as he dies less then 10 minutes in. So unless there's a deleted scene that gives us his reasoning we can only speculate any in-universe reason.  Out of universe reasons, the screenwriter and director needed a way to reinforce the point to the audience that these are not heroes but villains who will do anything including betraying their team in order to reduce time or escape from their jail sentence.

[Here's another possible explanation.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/YMMV/TheSuicideSquad)

Comment: You owe me one and a half hours...

Comment: @CGCampbell thats a shame

Comment: He's likely on the team because management knew he would sell them out to the enemy and cause the diversion.